# Python: keep same end of line character(s) when updating a file

Tags: python

Here's my code to do a find/replace on a file:

```
def updateFiles():
    fileToUpdt = tup[0]
    origVal = tup[1]
    newVal = tup[2]
    curfiledata = None

    with open(fileToUpdt, 'r') as curfile :
        curfiledata = curfile.read()

    curfiledata = curfiledata.replace(origVal, newVal)

    with open(fileToUpdt, 'w') as curfile:
        curfile.write(curfiledata)
```

The problem is that the line in input file is sometimes CRLF and sometimes just LF, but the write command always returns CRLF.  When the original line is LF, I want it to retain that newline and NOT put in the CR.  In other words, the newline should always be the same as it originally was in the input file, so if it was CRLF, it should remain CRLF, but if it was LF, then it should remain LF.  Is there someway I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add `b` (binary) to the read/write modes to make python ignore the lines and consider file as binary.

```
with open(fileToUpdt, 'rb') as curfile :
    curfiledata = curfile.read()
```

and

```
with open(fileToUpdt, 'wb') as curfile:
    curfile.write(curfiledata)
```

In python 2, that's enough, but in Python 3, `curfiledata` is of type `bytes`, no longer `str` since it is returned by a binary stream, so you have to make sure that `origVal` and `newVal` are `bytes` not `str`, for instance by using `encode` on the `str` object.

```
origVal = tup[1].encode()
newVal = tup[2].encode()
```

(depending on the data, you may have to use an extra argument to `encode`: ex: `encode("utf-8")`